# How to allow read and write access to only auth users in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am new to Firebase and Android. Here in Android, I have one button called <kbd>sign in</kbd> which registers auth users in Firebase and I am creating child object in database and I want to allow access to only auth registered users.

So please help me how to change in Firebase rules to allow for only auth users.

Firebase rules are now:

```
{
  "rules": {

        ".read": true,
        ".write": true

  }
}
```

auth users register:

```
Email              Providers     Created       Signed In     User UID
xxx@gmail.com                    Oct 4, 2016   Oct 4, 2016   PZJkEQnQZNZ
```

and the database:

```
chat-aa255
  - groupchat
      - KTOjXlA3Zwy38er
            - "msg":"hi"
            - "name":"one"
```

Please help me how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

It's because you are not authorized to the Database, check the Rules Tab in the Realtime database

If it's

```
{
  "rules": {
   ".read": "auth != null",
   ".write":"auth != null"
   }
 }
```

This means only authorized user's can write and read the Data.

Changing to

```
 {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write":true
    }
 }
```

Allows anyone to write the Database

When going for Production be sure to use the first one

Comment: ok rules changed....but please tell me how to display "groupchat" in database on auth user "xxx@gmail.com"

Comment: @BaskarP did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe it works:

```js
{
  "rules": {
     ".read": "auth.email == 'xxx@gmail.com'",
     ".write":"auth != null"
   }
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding tested/confirmed answer.